# Oracle 10G: ORA-06575: function in invalid state

Tags: function, oracle10g

I created a funcion like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax 
(p_sal IN  NUMBER(4)) 
RETURN NUMBER 
AS
v_tax NUMBER(4);
BEGIN 
v_tax:= CASE        
WHEN p_sal> 4000 THEN
p_sal*0.33       
WHEN p_sal >2500 THEN 
p_sal*0.25      
WHEN p_sal >1500 THEN 
p_sal*0.20     
ELSE 0         
END; 
RETURN v_tax;
END;
/
```

when i used this tax function in insert stmt like

```
INSERT INTO employees(eno, ename, job, join_date, sal, comm)
VALUES (7784,'allen','salesman',sysdate, 5000, tax(5000));
```

it shows the error like

```
ERROR: ORA-O6575: package or function tax is in invalid state.
```

can anyone suggest me how to make this function is in valid state?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your questions more carefully, and avoid ALLCAPS titles. Also, please accept relevant answers to your questions. See the FAQ at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 22):

Check errors with this command:

```
Select * from user_errors where name='Your function name'
```

Answer (score 10):

A function is compiled like this:

```
alter function tax compile;
```

Then, check for compilation errors with:

```
SHOW ERRORS
```

There are two main reasons while an object in Oracle is invalid:

1. The code is invalid (and gave an
   error message when you tried to
   compile it). The solution is of
   course to fix the error and then
   recompile it.
2. The object references another object and the other object was
   changed. The solution is to
   recompile the invalid object.

Also, some database connection drivers keep references to objects in the database. If the state of those object change in the database the references go stale and you will get an error similar to the one above.

Answer (score 4):

You can check error(s) with `SHOW ERROR` command

```
SQL> show error function Your_Function_Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your function compiled without errors. That's what Oracle's telling you with `ERROR: ORA-06575`.

Create your function with this statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax (p_sal IN NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER AS 
   v_tax NUMBER(4); 
BEGIN
   v_tax:= CASE
    WHEN p_sal> 4000 THEN p_sal*0.33
    WHEN p_sal >2500 THEN p_sal*0.25
    WHEN p_sal >1500 THEN p_sal*0.20
    ELSE 0
   END;
   RETURN v_tax;   
END;
```

You don't need the `(4)` on the parameter list when declaring a `NUMBER` in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-O6575: package or function tax is in invalid state.

means the function needs to be compiled. This statement

```
alter function tax compile;
```

should compile the function, but in some cases it completes without errors, but without actually doing anything. (This is the case in dBeaver).

In that case, locate the function in your SQL client and select the Compile function from a menu or toolbar.