# Error in stored procedure execution in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
create  procedure proc_insert_salary(salary_emp in NUMBER, 
                                     empid in NUMBER(10), 
                                     desig in varchar2(20))
begin
DECLARE
    gr_sal,hr,da,pf number;
BEGIN
    set hr:= salary_emp*(15/100);
    set da:= salary_emp*(8/100);
    set pf := salary_emp*(35/100);
    set gr_sal := salary_emp+hr+da-pf;
    insert into emp_salary_details values (empid,desig, salary_emp, gr_sal);
end;

call proc_insert_salary (45000,10100,'C.E.O.')
```

when I call this procedure it gives error its in invalid state.

Comment: You have use begin 2 times. remove 1st one

Comment: Begin can be used multiple times.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210379/oracle-10g-ora-06575-function-in-invalid-state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @Guneli's answer is adequate, there's really no reason for the second block in this case. The following would be equivalent (and slightly simpler).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert_salary (salary_emp IN NUMBER,
                                                empid IN NUMBER,
                                                desig IN VARCHAR2) AS
   hr NUMBER := salary_emp * (15 / 100);
   da NUMBER := salary_emp * (8 / 100);
   pf NUMBER := salary_emp * (35 / 100);
   gr_sal NUMBER := salary_emp + hr + da - pf;
BEGIN    
   INSERT INTO emp_salary_details
   VALUES      (empid,
                desig,
                salary_emp,
                gr_sal);
END;
/
```

Also, you should not that if you're going to have any other SQL in the same script (such as the `call`) then you need to end the procedure definition with a slash (/). This tells Oracle that procedure is finished and that it should compile it. Really, it's a good practice to always include it after procedural code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, try this instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_insert_salary(
    salary_emp IN NUMBER,
    empid      IN NUMBER,
    desig      IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    gr_sal NUMBER;
    hr     NUMBER;
    da     NUMBER;
    pf     NUMBER;
  BEGIN
    hr     := salary_emp*(15/100);
    da     := salary_emp*(8/100);
    pf     := salary_emp*(35/100);
    gr_sal := salary_emp+hr+da-pf;
    INSERT INTO emp_salary_details VALUES (empid,desig, salary_emp, gr_sal);
  END;
END;
```

The things to note are that:
1) You can not show the size for the parameters of subprograms in PL/SQL, so NUMBER(10) or VARCHAR2(20) are incorrect.
2)The one line declaration of variables is not supported in PL/SQL, so instead of `gr_sal,hr,da,pf number;` you should use

```
gr_sal NUMBER;
hr     NUMBER;
da     NUMBER;
pf     NUMBER;
```

3)To assign a value to variable you should not use SET, the ':=' is enough.
4)Also you have missed the 'end' clause for your second 'begin'.

Comment: Fine, but the variable inside the inner `BEGIN` block loses scope outside?!

Comment: It is a normal behavior for parameters of the inner blocks.